# How to import a sample from a library on github into android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm going to migrate to android studio.

I would like to use this library :

https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout

I followed below link steps to import this library :

https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

now, how can I use the sample of this project ?

[image]

I've tested the following steps but did not work:

file => import project

..\94\FoldableLayout-master\FoldableLayout-master\sample

file => import module

..\94\FoldableLayout-master\FoldableLayout-master\sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy/paste your sample folder into your project directory then enter below line in the `../project/settings.gradle` file :

```
> incldue ':sample'
```

Answer (score 0):

File => Open => ../Sample/Build.gradle

Comment: I got this error : Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in ptoject folder, go to project structue, import module then select the sample.