# Unable to import library into Android Studio manually

Tags: android, git, import, calendar

**Situation**
I am trying to use `Custom-Calendar-View` libary with my current project. Library's source code here:

`https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View`

I can get it to import if I use Gradle to import the library:
`compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.1'`

- Note that I used v1.1. The README on the Github says to use 1.0. After digging around `http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/custom-calendar-view-library-in-android`, I found that v1.1 has the latest updates and properly imports the library.

However, I am trying to manually import the library so I can play around with the sample project to better understand how things are working because I will eventually need to fork and modify the library to fit my usage.

**Error:**
`Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

**My Setup**

```
.
./app
./app/build.gradle
./libs
./libs/Custom-Calendar-View
./libs/Custom-Calendar-View/settings.gradle
./settings.gradle
```

**What I added**
1.Downloaded a zip of Custom-Calendar-View. Unzipped it. Copied it into `./libs`

2.Added in `./settings.gradle`

`include ':app', ':libs:Custom-Calendar-View`

3.Added in `./app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libs:Custom-Calendar-View')`
}
```

4.I tried `Clean Project`, `Rebuild Project`, `Sync`. Nothing works so far.

5.I even tried `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`

- Note that `Custom-Calendar-View` uses a submodule located at `Custom-Calendar-View/library`

**My Questions**
1.Do I need to import the library to be able to use play around with the sample project? If I import the library using Gradle, I don't see it in my project.

2.I really don't know what I am doing wrong. I feel like all these links give the same advice.

**Links**
[Cannot change dependencies of configuration (after enabling instant run)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878465/cannot-change-dependencies-of-configuration-after-enabling-instant-run)

[Configuration with name 'default' not found while building android project on gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178267/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-while-building-android-project-on-gr)

[Configuration with name 'default' not found. Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547364/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-android-studio)

[Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio)

[How to import a sample from a library on github into android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253090/how-to-import-a-sample-from-a-library-on-github-into-android-studio)

https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this post kinda solves the problem of manually importing a library:
    [unable to import library project in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736531/unable-to-import-library-project-in-android-studio)

However, I don't see the sample project anywhere.